# По(-)над — раздельно или через дефис?

Tags: орфография, предлоги, раздельно-дефис

"По(-)над лесом". **По-над** пишется раздельно или через дефис?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через дефис пишутся непроизводные предлоги из-за, по-за (разгов.:по-за домами), из-под, по-над. Интересно, а есть ещё какие-то?  Если кто-то может назвать, пусть напишет.

Comment: В принципе почти любая пара предлогов места и движения окказионально может стать основой для такого предлога.  
В разговорной речи фиксировал сочетания с над: "из-над", "в-над", "от-над" и т.д. Типа: "убарть образ из-над изголовья".

Answer (score 2):

> Я всё равно не понимаю его смысла.

По-над - этот предлог очень выразительный, он обозначает одновременно вдоль и над чем-нибудь.

> Я единственный из класса прочитал "Войну и Мир" полностью.

Ну тогда, может, и "Мертвые души" читали:   "Чичиков скорее за шапку да **по-за** спиною капитана-исправника выскользнул на крыльцо"

Comment: Смысл очень простой. "По" - вдоль рек (сравните - "сплав по реке"), "Над" - выше. Все вместе и даёт точную "локацию".

Answer (score 1):

Предлог **по-над** пишется через дефис и требует после себя творительного падежа.

Answer (score 1):

Примечание к примеру с "классикой".

"Классик" С. Островой написал так: "У леса на опушке зима жила в избушке ... Она сучила пряжу, она ткала холсты, ковала лядяные над реками мосты".

"Классик" Э. Хиль исполнял так: "У леса на опушке зима жила в избушке ... Она сучила пряжу, она ткала холсты, ковала ледяные да над реками мосты".

"Классик" behemothus написал так: "У леса на опушке зима жила в избушке ... Она сучила пряжу, она ткала холсты, ковала ледяные по-над реками мосты".

Comment: Хиль исполнял именно так, как дано в "первоисточнике".
И Островой писал так же.

Comment: Впрочем, не нравится Хиль, получите Владимир Семёныча.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCNO2RyDJn8
Тут уж, простите, шлангом не поприкидываешься. Кслассик сам писал -  сам исполнял.

*Тут стоит культурный парк по-над речкою,
В нем гуляю и плюю только в урны я,
Но ты, конечно, не поймешь, там, за печкою,
Потому ты - темнота некультурная.*

(Прям про вас, нет?)

Comment: Я не спорю. В частности, я не спорю с дилетантами.

Comment: Это хорошо.

Comment: На безрыбье и Хиль - классик, а Высоцкий - суперклассик (т.к. "коней своих нагайкой стегал по-над пропастью вдоль обрыва", например, цепи переменного тока).

Answer (score 0):

Непроизводные предлоги-сращения **из-за, из-под** и просторечные **по-за, по-над, по-под, для-ради, за-ради** пишутся [**через дефис**](http://www.orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=2174).

**Из-за** леса величаво выплывало солнце.
**Из-под** развесистой сирени вдруг с лаем выскочила собака.
Как хмельной, ветер весело гуляет **по-над** степью.
Оживленно бегут **по-под** снегом ручьи.
**Для-ради** важности надел он шапку набекрень.

Answer (score -5):

Что за извращение над русским языком? 22 года живу, первый раз такой предлог вижу. Я бы сказал, что нету такого предлога.

Comment: Больше читайте :-)

Comment: Ну нету такого предлога! Меня воротит от одного только его вида. Прямо как от молочного супа. 
Извините, но за 22 года хотя бы в школьной программе ЭТО должно было попасться. Но нет. Из этого вывод делаю я, что этого предлога нет.

Comment: То, что я Вас не знаю, еще не говорит о том, что Вас нет :-)) Предлог ПО-НАД существовал и прекрасно будет существовать без Вашего на то разрешения :-)

Comment: Если вы так уверены, что он есть, приведите пример из литературы, где его применяют, желательно ссылку. Посмотрел по словарям - да, есть. Но для себя я не знаю как его применять, мне он режет слух. 
Скорее всего вы учитель, всякого начитались. Даже каких-то узкоспециализированных предлогов. Чем "над лесом" отличается от "по-над лесом"? Первое просто не режет слух.

Comment: >>>"Больше читайте :-)"

Больше живите!!!

Comment: ТУЧИ



    ...

     По-над лесом,
     По-над кручей
     Повстречалась
     Туча
     С тучей.
     Засверкали
     Злые молнии!
     Расплескались
     Ведра полные!
     Туча
     С тучею
     Ругаются,
     Ведра по небу
     Катаются!..

     В небе
     Коромысло --
     Радуга
     Повисла.(http://lib.ru/TALES/SAPGIR/krasnyjshar.txt)

Comment: Предлог по-над часто употребляется в произведениях устного народного творчества и в произведениях, стилизованных под фольклор.

Comment: Много примеров в Национальном корпусе русского языка. Вот некоторые: "По-над квартирой затем всю ночь веял крепкий запах валерьянки, аромат слез, просьба о сочувствии, белый флаг капитуляции". [Л.Петрушевская. Три лица]. Сравните: "запах веял по квартире" и "запах веял над квартирой". Или вот еще: "Днем глухими ударами-качками бьет сразу с двух сторон ― из-за Ангары и по-над горой". [В.Распутин. На родине] "Определенно подтверждался первоначальный вывод: эти тридцать ― сорок шагов по-над берегом, безусловно, были самыми опасными на всем пути". [Еремей Парнов. Александрийская гемма]

Comment: Как я понял, можно соединить 2 совершенно разных предлога и это будет правильно. Великий и могучий...
Я всё равно не понимаю его смысла. И поэтому применять его не собираюсь.

    Больше живите!!! Тогда и классику знать будете.

Я единственный из класса прочитал "Войну и Мир" полностью. Остальные по каким-то кратким содержаниям...

Comment: Не мудрено, что такой предлог Вы или не встречали, или не заметили. По-за, по-над  и др.  действительно встречаются реже,они считаются диалектными.  Но они очень выразительные и поэтому живут не только в разговорной речи, но и используются авторами художественных произведений. Где-то же Вы такой предлог встретили, коли вопрос задали?

Comment: Есть у хора им.Пятницкого одна песня, она мне очень нравилась в своё время (да и сейчас тоже нравится). "Дороженька". Красиво поют. Ну как всегда они, мастера-хоровики: "По-над речкой расстилается туман. Росы чистые упали на траву. Я надену сво

Comment: свой бордовый сарафан. Я малины, красной ягоды, нарву". Песня советская, в духе Сталинских времён. Но мы ведь изучаем русский язык, не обращая внимания на политику. Ну и как лучше звучит фраза: "Над речкой..." или "По-над речкой..."? Да, правильнее сказать "Над..", но гораздо краше звучит: "По-над...". Тем более в хоровой песне (предназначенной, как правило, для коллективного слушателя). Пусть Инакомыслящий не использует этот чудовищный предлог. Предлогу от этого хуже не станет. Со временем, возможно, он что-то важное переиначит в своём мировоззрении, и на душе у него станет спокойно-спокойно