# Значение предлога «по-над»

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, предлоги

У Высоцкого:

> «...Вдоль обрыва, **по-над** пропастью...»

Каково значение этого предлога? Он определяет местоположение?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6922/По-над-раздельно-или-через-дефис схожий вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Из словаря:

**ПО-НАД**, предлог. чем **Трад.-нар**. Над чем-л., вдоль чего-л., расположенного внизу. П. берегом ходят тучи.

**Предлог ПО** обозначает направление движения вдоль пропасти, **предлог НАД** - расположение над пропастью, то есть почти над пропастью, вдоль самого края.

Answer (score 1):

> По-над. Предлог, определяющий местоположение?

Да. Но не просто местоположение, а в сочетании с направлением движения. 
Первая часть такого составного предлога всегда означает направление, а вторая — место. В современном нормативном русском языке сохранилось всего два таких предлога: "из-за" и "из-под", а так же близкие образования типа "извне", "снаружи", "вдоль по", с аналогичной моделью (куда+где?), но подчиняющиеся по историческим причинам другим орфографическим правилам.

В народном языке таким образований много больше, "по-над" одно из них. Однако в этом случае возникает небольшая сложность в понимании. Предлог "по" имеет значение, сочетающее в себе значение места и движения ("трамвай ходит по улице" — это и "где", и "куда", "бегать по двору" — "где?", а "идти по бревну" — скорее всего "куда?", то есть "на тот берег", например).

Поэтому надо всегда смотреть в какой функции выступает этот предлог. В сочетании "по-над" у "по" явно предлог направления (близкое к "вдоль": "по-над речкою", "по-над пропастью"), а в других случаях ("вдоль по Питерской") это просто предлог места.

К сожалению, это четкое понимание смысла подобного составного предлога часто теряется и возникают ошибочные толкования. "Дым **по-над** крышей", "по-над рекой расстилался туман, птица пролетала **по-над** лесом".
https://pishu-pravilno.livejournal.com/1489342.html

"Дом" и "лес" не имеют однонаправленной протяженности, да и туман над рекою все-таки стоит, не движется. "По" здесь тоже предлог места, он ничего не добавляет к "над", поэтому использование составного предлога здесь выглядит просто избыточным, во всяком случае значение его иное, чем у Высоцкого.